# Is there anyway to send WhatsApp message using node js?

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

Is anyone aware about api that can be used to send WhatsApp message using node.

Api like whatsmate have stopped their premium services and only provide trial account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official whatsapp API, whatever you can find on the internet is "illegal" and whatsapp will ban them eventually. Check this one API who was quite good at the start:

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party vendors like Kaleyra to send whatsapp messages. They have extensive documentation showing how to send these messages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).