# Sending WhatsApp Messages using personal number with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

Can I use Twilio for sending messages on WhatsApp using my personal number. In their docs, they mention that they provide their own number for communication, but can we somehow use our own personal number?
And if not, is there any other service provider (or even a hack) that I can use for doing the same thing.
Basically, I want to create a script for wishing my friends happy birthday on WhatsApp.

Comment: Why don't you simply use WhatsApp business account? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started/

Comment: "Cellphones - Can be used as long as the number has not been used for WhatsApp in the last 6 months." - on the link you provided. As I mentioned, I want to send these messages from my own personal number registered with WhatsApp and being used by my regularly.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697613/is-there-anyway-to-send-whatsapp-message-using-node-js

Comment: The solution on this repository is invalid now. The repository has been wiped out.

Comment: Dude read that asnwer, "There is no official whatsapp API, whatever you can find on the internet is "illegal" and whatsapp will ban them eventually."

Comment: and check out that comment there is a fork of that project

Comment: And it is illegal according to WhatsApp Terms

Comment: So basically there's no way around

Comment: STILL THERE IS A FORK AVAILABLE - https://github.com/Willyham/botsapp

Comment: But, eventually it will also be banned. That's what I'm saying. There's not permanent solution.

Comment: Yes, and if you want to do hobby project like sending automated bday wishes then Probably you could try the same concept on Facebook. you can easily utilize messanger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, in order to use your own WhatsApp brand, phone number(s), and
>   message templates through Twilio, your use case must be reviewed and
>   approved by WhatsApp. Twilio is working directly with WhatsApp to
>   handle approvals for our customers. As of early 2019, approvals are in
>   limited availability, so many customers are still testing with the
>   Sandbox.

Something that caught my eye in [twilio whatsapp docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017771714-How-Can-I-Get-my-Own-WhatsApp-Twilio-Number-for-Use-in-Production-).

I guess for now you should stick to the sandbox environment twilio has setup and for sending birthday wishes it should be good as it has a daily limit of 1000 unique users.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I also read this. But the problem with this solution in my case is that it won't seem natural. A birthday wish coming from a number say, +413739221, is kinda making me not use it.

Comment: Plus one more catch in the solution, all the users (in my case, friends) must be registered with the sandbox. That's a real bummer.

Comment: yes, I get it. But I guess you won't be able to do it with twilio. However there are other solutions. Check this out https://github.com/dwintechnology/whatsapp-chapi

Comment: There's also this library, but use with care as it might result in a ban for your phone number on whatsapp platform, but this is for python, maybe you can change your preferred language https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup. It's js wrapper https://www.npmjs.com/package/yowjs

Comment: What about this whatsapp-chapi? Does this also comes with consequences???

Comment: @saranshabd I don't think so, but don't take my word for it because I have not used it. Maybe a quick google search would help you in that matter.